# Rendering a composition of +-5000 React components takes forever

Tags: reactjs

I have this render

```
        render() {
        let rows = []

        if (this.state.loaded) {
         //this.props.totalWeeks is 5000
          for (let i = 1; i <= this.props.totalWeeks; i++) {
            rows.push(<CalendarFields key={i} weekId={i} weeksToRegisterDate={this.props.weeksToRegisterDate} currentWeek={this.props.currentWeek} description={this.getDescription(i)} rating={this.getRating(i)} />)
          }
          return <div className="fieldsContainer ">{rows}</div>
        } else {
          return <p>fetching data...</p>
        }


      }
```

And the amount of time that it takes to be displayed in the app is enormous. Around 5-6 seconds, so the screen is empty while it happens, I can add a load screen while the dom is rendered I guess. But cant I speed it somehow?

Is there any way to speed it? Its basically a composition of small cubes 20px height, 20px width, with custom props being passed for each one

**EDIT**: It has been basically solved using a production build

**EDIT2**: No it hasnt, it was an illusion

**EDIT3**: whole original code

```
import React from 'react'
import CalendarFields from './CalendarFields'
import { getUserId } from '../services/userInfo.js'
import API from '../services/axiosObject.js';
import constants from '../constants.js'
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import './CalendarGrid.css'

class CalendarGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      fieldsInfo: [],
      loaded: false
    }

  }



  componentDidMount() {

    const userId = getUserId();

    API.get(constants.urlBackend + '/getUserFieldsInfo/' + userId).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        fieldsInfo: response.data,
        loaded: true
      }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.fieldsInfo)
      })

    })
  }




  getDescription(id) {
    var newArray = this.state.fieldsInfo.filter(function (el) {
      return el.week_number == id
    })
    return newArray[0].text;
  }

  getRating(id) {
    var newArray = this.state.fieldsInfo.filter(function (el) {
      return el.week_number == id
    })
    return newArray[0].rating;
  }


  render() {

    let rows = []

    if (this.state.loaded) {
      for (let i = 1; i <= this.props.totalWeeks; i++) {
        rows.push(<CalendarFields key={i} weekId={i} weeksToRegisterDate={this.props.weeksToRegisterDate} currentWeek={this.props.currentWeek} description={this.getDescription(i)} rating={this.getRating(i)} />)
      }
      return <div className="fieldsContainer ">{rows}</div>
    } else {
      return <div className="gridLoadingContainer"><CircularProgress color="primary" iconStyle={"width: 150, height:150"}/></div>
    }


  }
}

export default CalendarGrid;
```

This is my try to implement the component

```
    import React from 'react'
import CalendarFields from './CalendarFields'
import { getUserId } from '../services/userInfo.js'
import API from '../services/axiosObject.js';
import constants from '../constants.js'
import { CircularProgress } from '@material-ui/core';
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";
import './CalendarGrid.css'

class CalendarGrid extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      fieldsInfo: [],
      loaded: false,
      rows: ""
    }

  }



  componentDidMount() {

    const userId = getUserId();

    API.get(constants.urlBackend + '/getUserFieldsInfo/' + userId).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        fieldsInfo: response.data,
        loaded: true
      }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.fieldsInfo)
      })

    })
  }




  getDescription(id) {
    var newArray = this.state.fieldsInfo.filter(function (el) {
      return el.week_number == id
    })
    return newArray[0].text;
  }

  getRating(id) {
    var newArray = this.state.fieldsInfo.filter(function (el) {
      return el.week_number == id
    })
    return newArray[0].rating;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.loaded ){
      this.composer();
    }
  }
  composer(){
     var row = ({ index, style }) => {
      const { weeksToRegisterDate, currentWeek } = this.props;
      console.log("index")
      console.log(index)
      if(this.state.loaded){
        console.log(this.getDescription(index))
        return (
           <CalendarFields
             key={index}
             weekId={index}
             style={style}
             weeksToRegisterDate={weeksToRegisterDate}
             currentWeek={currentWeek}
             description={this.getDescription(index)}
             rating={ this.getRating(index)}

            />
         );
      }

    }
    this.setState({
      rows: row
    }, () => console.log(this.state.rows))
  }



  render() {

    let rows = []

    if (this.state.loaded) {
      const { totalWeeks, weeksToRegisterDate, currentWeek } = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="fieldsContainer ">

              <List
                className="List"
                height={1000}
                itemCount={totalWeeks}
                itemSize={300}
                width={1000}
              >
                {this.state.rows}
              </List>


        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <div className="gridLoadingContainer"><CircularProgress color="primary" iconStyle={"width: 150, height:150"}/></div>
    }


  }
}

export default CalendarGrid;
```

Not really getting it to work tho. I tried to do so, because it is failing to wait for the data fetching apparently

Comment: What about pagination?

Comment: @Rashomon sadly it would break my app logic, I cant use pagination, since tis against the app concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue of slowness happens when the browser has a huge number of DOM elements to render and it isn't able to efficiently process events such as scroll on those elements.

The idea to solve such approaches is to called virtualization or windowing wherein you only render as many items in the DOM as are visible to the users +- a few elements as buffer. This way the browser has few elements to process.

The first challenge here comes when we have to show a scrollbar suggesting there are quite a few elements. The way we solve this is by actually knowing how much is the height for each row and in turn calculate the total height possible.

The calculations are reduced significantly we the row sizes are same and fixed, for varying row sizes its a little complex

You can either choose to implement this logic yoursself or even better use a library i.e [`react-window`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) or [`react-virtualzed`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) depending on the complexity of your list.

`react-window` is a trimmed down and a light weight version and should suffice for your above usecase

You can implement it for your code like

```
import { FixedSizeList as List } from "react-window";
import AutoSizer from "react-virtualized-auto-sizer";

...
row = ({ index, style }) => {
  const { weeksToRegisterDate, currentWeek } = this.props;
   return (
      <CalendarFields
        key={index}
        weekId={index}
        style={style}
        weeksToRegisterDate={weeksToRegisterDate}
        currentWeek={currentWeek}
        description={this.getDescription(index)}
        rating={this.getRating(index)} 
       />
    );
}

render () {
    if (!this.state.loaded)  {
       return <p>fetching data...</p>
    }
    const { totalWeeks, weeksToRegisterDate, currentWeek } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="fieldsContainer ">
        <AutoSizer>
          {({ height, width }) => (
            <List
              className="List"
              height={height}
              itemCount={totalWeeks.length}
              itemSize={/* set you list item size here */}
              width={width}
            >
              {this.row}
            </List>
          )}
        </AutoSizer>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding this will onyl work on a one directioned list . Horizontal ,or vertical, but not both. So far I havent been able to implement it, but i will keep testing

Comment: there are other components exposed by react virtualised if you wish virtulization in both direction

Comment: Actually to be honest i finally had time to test the production build, and the speed increased by x1000000 , it loads in a fraction of second. But i will keep it in mind. I will give you the bounty when its unlocked

Comment: I am happy that it worked well for you, but in general windowing is the way to go for such applications, you can also try to implement both ways, I will try to update my answer considering both directions if I have time

Comment: those two properties ````description={this.getDescription(index)}
        rating={this.getRating(index)} ```` are failing, "cannot read property of undefined" , it seems that the composition doesnt wait for the fetch in the parent component to finish. But its weird, since the render is insida a loaded state

Comment: Make sure you use `if (!this.state.loaded)  {` as the condition

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use windowing.

> Windowing or List virtualization is a concept of only rendering or write the visible portion in the current “ window ” to the DOM.

See [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window) for its possible implementation.

Comment: I will check it out, Ive noticed too that my current build is a development build now. Maybe switching to a production build can speed it up