# Javascript / HTML How to render a lot of data onto a screen while staying performant?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

Say I have for example a 520 page page book with more than 6,200 lines inside. Each line can be anywhere from 5 to 300 characters long. I have these stored in a file (line delimited). I am trying to display everything on the screen for the user to read, however I cant find the best way.

Rendering all 6,000+ elements at once will be extremely slow, especially on mobile devices.

For now I am using a snippet of code that essentially fires an event when the last line is viewed and then loads the next set of lines. This works on chrome flawlessly but on Safari it is jerky because of iPhone momentum scrolling.

The other option I had was to simply draw the text to a canvas that would be big enough to be scrollable, but that would require a canvas about 1,000,000 pixels in height so that is not feasible.

I also tried implementing a custom canvas scrolling method where on touch the canvas contents get pushed down a certain amount and dynamically load new content, however this was super slow and laggy.

All of these methods have their own pros and cons, but the first seems the easiest to fix. Can I somehow disable safari momentum scrolling so I can manually set the window's scrollY?

One thing to note is that none of the content is dynamic. Its all the same text, just maybe a different font size on different devices, thats it. I could pre-render it, but im not sure how to do that either.

**Tl;dr My problem is simply finding a good Javascript library or way (in react) to display a list of 6,000+ lines that all have different heights.**

Thanks.

Comment: "Rendering all 6,000+ elements at once will be extremely slow" no it won't

Comment: Are you _sure_ that rendering them all in one page is a good idea? You could split it into different files or implement a page system where the user can go to a next or previous page, and then you add that page's content to the DOM.

Comment: @AndyRay I tried simply using an array map in React's render function. Is there a better way to render it?

Comment: @code I don't want it paged, I want it like an infinite scroll where you can just keep scrolling.

Comment: use Scroll event to fetch data as you scroll down

Comment: @TVOGaming Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking future questions. It's trivial for a web browser to show an entire book's text contents in one page, even for long novels. The whole thing would only be a few kb of text, smaller than most images. Without showing us any code we can only guess what you're doing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering a composition of +-5000 React components takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560573/rendering-a-composition-of-5000-react-components-takes-forever)

Comment: @AndyRay takes about 300ms to render for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized)? You can read the following on its `README.md`:

> React components for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular data.

And that too on an [example](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List):

> The list below is windowed (or "virtualized") meaning that only the visible rows are rendered.

It can help you perform rendering so much data.

P.S.:

You said that you already tried something like this:

> For now I am using a snippet of code that essentially fires an event when the last line is viewed and then loads the next set of lines. This works on chrome flawlessly but on Safari it is jerky because of iPhone momentum scrolling.

But since `react-virtualized` is a library, it might be a problem already fixed by the library.

Comment: Correct answer but worth noting this lib is fairly outdated now (no hooks). https://tanstack.com/virtual/v3 worth a look.

Comment: I took a look at the TanStack website and it looks pretty nice. Very good recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamThomas the creator made a [new version](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window).

Comment: Yeh, I know about that. Its better, but still no hooks. Tanstack one is super super new

Comment: I created a library that might solve your problem. Here is the link with load-on-demand example, but there are many others. Dynamic row heights are also supported. https://af-utils.vercel.app/virtual/examples/list/LoadOnDemand